# Data from AngularJS local storage service not rendering unless page refreshed

Tags: html, angular, local-storage

I am building a small AngularJS project and I have encountered a problem that I want to ask you guys about.
I am using angular-local-storage module to store some data coming from my API into the browser's local storage. 
In one of my controllers I assign this data to a variable in the $scope object and try to render it in the view as follows:

controller:

```
angular.module('Dashboard')

.controller('DashboardController',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'localStorageService',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, localStorageService) {
            $scope.userData = localStorageService.get('userData');
        }]);
```

And the view:

```
<div class="row">
<h4>Welcome to your dashboard <strong>{{userData.personalUserInfo.name}}</strong>!</h4>
```

When I log into the app (which is when the data is fetched from API and stored in local store by key 'userData'), the view is incomplete, I get only "Welcome to your dashboard !" without the name there. When I go to the dev console and look at the localStorage of my browser, the entry "userData" is there, it is just not rendered.
Then when I hit F5 and refresh the page, the name appears.

Do you have any ideas why that is and what can be done to fix that?
Cheers!

Comment: It should be parsed down to JSON like `$scope.userData = 
 JSON.parse(localStorageService.get('userData'))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$scope.$watch` for this, like following:

```js
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return localStorageService.get('userData');
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal)
    $scope.userData = newVal;
})
```

`$scope.$watch`, will execute second `function` each time return value of first `function` is changed.

Comment: Hey @Vipin Kumar, thanks, this works, however it creates a loop of calls apparently. I get this on the console:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: Are you sure, this (error) is happening because of above code. Or, you have added some other code in `callback function`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create plunker/fiddler with issue reproduced.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the delay. I failed to create a working plunker of my issue and that made me think :) I solved the issue by noticing that I was setting my localStorage value after an asynchronous call to my API, but did not put that localStorageService.set() inside the success callback. After I changed that it worked :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: good to know. please upvote and accept the answer if satisfied